# How to understand this sentence "Identify issues that you needs to escalate to appropriate people in AAA"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Suppose `AAA` is the company name I work for.

When a new person joins to the company, there will be a "buddy" assigned to him/her, and he/she will receive a letter tells what a buddy will do for him/her:

```
Identify issues that you needs to escalate to appropriate people in AAA
```

As the buddy, I found I can't understand this sentence correctly. After discussed with some colleagues, I found two explanations:

1. I will help the new person find what he/she needs to do or to improve, so he/she can be a good employee
2. I will help the new person to find other proper people to solve his/her problems when I can't solve it by myself

Which one is correct, or neither?

(PS: is the word `needs` correct in the sentence? Or should it be `need`?)

Comment: **Need** is correct because the subject of the verb is **you**. We only use **needs** when the subject is **he**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Identify issues that you *need* to escalate to appropriate people in AAA.

Yes, it should be *need*.

The meaning of the phrase is that during training/orientation, there will be some issues that the two of you can't resolve. They might be technical or procedural matters, or personnel related ones. So that they can be properly addressed, it is asking you you identify those issues, and then inform the "appropriate people" (perhaps dept. heads or managers).

It is *need* because this has to happen when the two of you can't solve some difficulty.
*escalate* means to move it up the organizational chart to higher level employees.

Comment: "Appropriate people" would be those who are more senior to you (which would be practically anyone since you are a new hire) with more responsibility or knowledge, that is why "escalate" is used.

Comment: @Peter The situation involves the current employee and a new hire. We don't know the level of the current employee.

Comment: @Peter and user3169: So far, I though **escalate** means make or become more sever or serious, what does it mean here? I've never seen such usage.

Comment: "inform them to"  is ungrammatical.  The direct object of **inform** in this usage is the person who is being told of something, but here, you're referring to the issues. The sentence wants **tell** or **bring**.

Comment: @Cardinal Yes, but also moving up the responsibility ladder. It could be due to severity (like resolving a personnel problem) or just to a more experienced person (like when the engineer has to ask the administration manager about business issues).